# Adding Multiple rows to a Postgres database

Tags: python, postgresql, dictionary, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

EDIT: added more of the code to better understand what I'm trying to do

I'm using Flask, pandas, and flask-SQLAchemy. currently, I'm using pandas to upload an excel file and display that in an editable html table to confirm all the data and edit anything before posting all the data. where I'm having an issue is taking all those rows of data and adding them to my Postgres database as new entries. I can only get it to post the first row. any help would be apprenticed.

Heres the HTML used to display the editable HTML table as a form:

```
<!-- Display Uploaded excel file -->

<h2 id="Title" class="mig-gray">Submitted Data</h2>

<table class="table table-striped table-sm" id="uploading">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">UID</th>
      <th scope="col">Names</th>
      <th scope="col">Title</th>
      <th scope="col">Order</th>
      <th scope="col">Catergory</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    {% for key,value in df.iterrows()|sort(reverse=true, attribute="catergory") %}
    <form action="/pushtodatabase" method="POST" name="uploadform">
      <tr id="{{ loop.index }}">
        <td> {{ loop.index }} </td>
        <td><input class="form-control-plaintext" type="text" name="name" value="{{ value["Names"] }}" /></td>
        <td><input class="form-control-plaintext" type="text" name="title" value="{{ value["Title"] }}" /></td>
        <td><input class="form-control-plaintext" type="text" name="order" value="{{ value["Order"] }}" /></td>
        <td><select class="mig-black custom-select" name="catergory" id="catergory" method="GET">
            {% for catergory in catergory %}
            {% if catergory.id == value["Catergory"]|int %}
            <option value="{{catergory.id}}" selected>Session {{catergory.title}} - {{catergory.name}}</option>
            {% else %}
            <option value="{{catergory.id}}">Session {{catergory.title}} - {{catergory.name}}</option>
            {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
          </select>
        </td>
      </tr>
      {% endfor %}
  </tbody>
</table>
<input class="col-md-6 btn btn-success" type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<hr>
```

Route to Upload Excel File:

```
### Route for Upload Excel
@app.route('/upload', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def upload():
    df = []
    catergory = Catergory.query.order_by(Catergory.id).all()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        df = pandas.read_excel(request.files.get('fileupload'), na_filter=False)
        return render_template('uploadedfile.html', catergory=catergory, df=df)

    return render_template('upload.html')
```

Here's my current route to return the submitted data

```
### Route to Upload to database
@app.route('/pushtodatabase', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
@login_required
def pushtodatabase():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        test = request.form.to_dict(flat=False)
        return test

        flash("Your added", 'success')
        return redirect("/")

return render_template('uploadedfile.html', catergory=catergory, df=df)
```

This is the results in my browser from that:

```
{
category: [
  "1",
  "2",
  "3",
  "4",
  "5",
  "6",
  "7",
  "8",
  "1"
],
name: [
  "Matt Leigh",
  "Alishia Holcomb",
  "Maud Bell",
  "Lester Stuart",
  "Anabella Rasmussen",
  "Malachy Cote",
  "Danyal Halliday",
  "Kaine Hills",
  "Axl Pennington"
],
order: [
   "a",
   "b",
   "c",
   "d",
   "e",
   "f",
   "g",
   "h",
   "i"
],
title: [
   "Guide Dog Instructor",
   "Head Start Director",
   "Geomorphologist",
   "High School Music Director",
   "Psychological Operations Or Civil Affairs",
   "Poultry Inseminator",
   "Speech and Language Specialist",
   "Aerospace Control And Warning Systems, Weapons Director",
   "Drywall Taper Helper"
]
}
```

I want to take this data and break it up into its respected row so I can post each row as a database entry. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

figured it out, required some more pandas!

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    test = request.form.to_dict(flat=False)
    df = pandas.DataFrame.from_dict(test)
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        name = row["name"]
        title = row["title"]
        catergory = row["catergory"]
        winnerorder = row["order"]
        new_winners = Winners(name=name, title=title, catergory=catergory, winnerorder=winnerorder)

        db.session.add(new_winners)
    db.session.commit()
```